# Split XML into smaller chunks based on the id of the grandchild

Tags: java, xml

I have an xml that should be split into smaller chunks by unique BookId node. Basically I need to filter out each book into separate xml having the same structure of the initial XML.

The purpose of that is - requirement to validate each smaller XML against XSD to determine which Book/PendingBook is not valid.

Note that **Books** node can contain both **Book** and **PendingBook** nodes.

**Initial XML:**

```
<Main xmlns="http://some/url/name">
  <Books>

    <Book>
      <IdentifyingInformation>
        <ID>
          <Year>2021</Year>
          <BookId>001</BookId>
          <BookDateTime>2021-05-10T12:35:00</BookDateTime>
        </ID>
      </IdentifyingInformation>
    </Book>

    <Book>
      <IdentifyingInformation>
        <ID>
          <Year>2020</Year>
          <BookId>002</BookId>
          <BookDateTime>2021-05-10T12:35:00</BookDateTime>
        </ID>
      </IdentifyingInformation>
    </Book>

    <PendingBook>
      <IdentifyingInformation>
        <ID>
          <Year>2020</Year>
          <BookId>003</BookId>
          <BookDateTime>2021-05-10T12:35:00</BookDateTime>
        </ID>
      </IdentifyingInformation>
    </PendingBook>

    <OtherInfo>...</OtherInfo>

  </Books>
</Main>
```

The result should be like next xmls:

**Book_001.xml (BookId = 001):**

```
<Main xmlns="http://some/url/name">
  <Books>

    <Book>
      <IdentifyingInformation>
        <ID>
          <Year>2021</Year>
          <BookId>001</BookId>
          <BookDateTime>2021-05-10T12:35:00</BookDateTime>
        </ID>
      </IdentifyingInformation>
    </Book>

    <OtherInfo>...</OtherInfo>

  </Books>
</Main>
```

**Book_002.xml (BookId = 002):**

```
<Main xmlns="http://some/url/name">
  <Books>

    <Book>
      <IdentifyingInformation>
        <ID>
          <Year>2020</Year>
          <BookId>002</BookId>
          <BookDateTime>2021-05-10T12:35:00</BookDateTime>
        </ID>
      </IdentifyingInformation>
    </Book>

    <OtherInfo>...</OtherInfo>

  </Books>
</Main>
```

**PendingBook_003.xml (BookId = 003):**

```
<Main xmlns="http://some/url/name">
  <Books>

    <PendingBook>
      <IdentifyingInformation>
        <ID>
          <Year>2021</Year>
          <BookId>003</BookId>
          <BookDateTime>2021-05-10T12:35:00</BookDateTime>
        </ID>
      </IdentifyingInformation>
    </PendingBook>

    <OtherInfo>...</OtherInfo>

  </Books>
</Main>
```

So far I fetched only each **ID** node into smaller xmls. And created root element manually.

Ideally I want to copy all elements from initial xml and put into Books node single Book/PendingBook node.

My java sample:

```
package com.main;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ExtractXmls {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String inputFile = "C:/pathToXML/Main.xml";

        File xmlFile = new File(inputFile);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!

        XPathFactory xfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xfactory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression allBookIdsExpression = xpath.compile("//Books/*/IdentifyingInformation/ID/BookId/text()");
        NodeList bookIdNodes = (NodeList) allBookIdsExpression.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        //Save all the products
        List<String> bookIds = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < bookIdNodes.getLength(); ++i) {
            Node bookId = bookIdNodes.item(i);

            System.out.println(bookId.getTextContent());
            bookIds.add(bookId.getTextContent());
        }

        //Now we create and save split XMLs
        for (String bookId : bookIds)
        {
            //With such query I can find node based on bookId
            String xpathQuery = "//ID[BookId='" + bookId + "']";
            xpath = xfactory.newXPath();
            XPathExpression query = xpath.compile(xpathQuery);
            NodeList bookIdNodesFiltered = (NodeList) query.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            System.out.println("Found " + bookIdNodesFiltered.getLength() + " bookId(s) for bookId " + bookId);

            //We store the new XML file in bookId.xml e.g. 001.xml
            Document aamcIdXml = dBuilder.newDocument();
            Element root = aamcIdXml.createElement("Main"); //Here I'm recreating root element (don't know if I can avoid it and copy somehow structure of initial xml)
            aamcIdXml.appendChild(root);
            for (int i = 0; i < bookIdNodesFiltered.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = bookIdNodesFiltered.item(i);
                Node copyNode = aamcIdXml.importNode(node, true);
                root.appendChild(copyNode);
            }


            //At the end, we save the file XML on disk
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(aamcIdXml);

            StreamResult result =  new StreamResult(new File("C:/pathToXML/" + bookId.trim() + ".xml"));
            transformer.transform(source, result);

            System.out.println("Done for " + bookId);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far. You will get help quickly.

Comment: I updated my question with more info. Hope it is much clear now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special purpose language designed to transform XML files including extracting needed nodes. Additionally, you can pass parameters from application layer like Java into XSLT (just like SQL)!

Specifically, iteratively passed in the XPath retrieved BookIds by Java into XSLT named `param`. By the way, no extensive code re-factoring is needed since you already have the `transformer` set up to run XSLT!

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl, a special .xml)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- INITIALIZE PARAMETER  -->
  <xsl:param name="param_bookId"/>
  
  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Books">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Book[descendant::BookId = $param_bookId] |
                                   PendingBook[descendant::BookId = $param_bookId]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="OtherInfo"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDjimW)</kbd>

**Java** *(no rebuild of trees)*

```
// ... same code as reading XML input    ...
// ... same code as creating bookIdNodes ...

String curr_bookId = null;
String outputXML = null;

String xslFile = "C:/Path/To/XSL/Style.xsl";
Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File(xslFile));

// ITERATE THROUGH EACH BOOK ID
for (int i = 0; i < bookIdNodes.getLength(); ++i) {
     Node bookId = bookIdNodes.item(i);

     System.out.println(bookId.getTextContent());
     curr_bookId = bookId.getTextContent();
        
     // CONFIGURE TRANSFORMER
     TransformerFactory prettyPrint = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
     Transformer transformer = prettyPrint.newTransformer(xslt);
        
     transformer.setParameter("param_bookId", curr_bookId);   // PASS PARAM
     transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
     transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
     transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
     transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
     transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
        
     // TRANSFORM AND OUTPUT FILE TO DISK 
     outputXML = "C:/Path/To/XML/BookId_" + curr_bookId + ".xml";

     DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
     StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(outputXML));       
     transformer.transform(source, result);
}
```

Comment: Wow.. "Online Demo" works perfectly fine, exactly what I need.
But Java doesn't change initial xml for some reason... trying to figure out why.

Comment: Does the `System.out.println` print out any or *different* BookIDs? Ideally, this value passes into XSLT with each pass of loop.

Comment: Yes. It prints out proper BookIDs and proper IDs are passed to the transformer but for some reason I'm receiving copy of the initial XML. 
In XSL only 1 line is different comparing Demo version and XSLT you shared:
<xsl:param name="param_bookId"/>
Maybe smthg wrong around that place.. hmm

Comment: Simply remove `doc:` prefixes in XSLT. See edit. Just realized in Java by default DOM documents are not namespace aware. (By the way, you never use `factory` so the `// never forget this!` line is not needed). And do not set `dbFactory` to be namespace aware or your XPath will not work.

Comment: One more question:
To use XSLT approach I need to save result of transformation somewhere on a disk, right?
Can I somehow split, validate each smaller xml on a fly?

I mean, instead of saving files to the disc I would like to convert to byte input stream, validate it and move on.

Comment: This XSLT will transform to an XML tree. You do not have to save to disk to process. Look into `DOMResult` (instead of `StreamResult`) for *result* object.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it to work. You could change your XPath in your loop iterating the book IDs to get the `Book` or `PendingBook` Element and then use it. Also you need to create `Books` element in addition to `Main` and append `Book` or `PendingBook` to the newly created `Books` Element.

The XPath is : `//ancestor::*[IdentifyingInformation/ID/BookId=bookId]`

It gets the ancestor of the element whose bookId matches to that of the ID in the current iteration i.e. the `Book` or `PendingBook` element.

```
//Now we create and save split XMLs
        for (String bookId : bookIds)
        {
            //With such query I can find node based on bookId
            String xpathQuery = "//ancestor::*[IdentifyingInformation/ID/BookId=" + bookId + "]";
            xpath = xfactory.newXPath();
            XPathExpression query = xpath.compile(xpathQuery);
            NodeList bookIdNodesFiltered = (NodeList) query.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            System.out.println("Found " + bookIdNodesFiltered.getLength() + " bookId(s) for bookId " + bookId);

            //We store the new XML file in bookId.xml e.g. 001.xml
            Document aamcIdXml = dBuilder.newDocument();
            Element root = aamcIdXml.createElement("Main");
            Element booksNode = aamcIdXml.createElement("Books");
            root.appendChild(booksNode);
            //Here I'm recreating root element (don't know if I can avoid it and copy somehow structure of initial xml)
            aamcIdXml.appendChild(root);
            String bookName = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < bookIdNodesFiltered.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = bookIdNodesFiltered.item(i);
                Node copyNode = aamcIdXml.importNode(node, true);
                bookName = copyNode.getNodeName();
                booksNode.appendChild(copyNode);
            }


            //At the end, we save the file XML on disk
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(aamcIdXml);

            StreamResult result =  new StreamResult(new File(bookName + "_" + bookId.trim() + ".xml"));
            transformer.transform(source, result);

            System.out.println("Done for " + bookId);
        }
```

And also I modified code to name the file as you needed like `Book_001.xml`.

Comment: Thanks. This also works. 
But XSLT approach is simpler and faster